# Certificates were removed when I install using C#

Tags: c#, certificate

I installed a certificate using the following code:

```
 X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root);
 store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
 X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
 collection.Import("Path", "Password", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
 store.AddRange(collection);
```

the certificate is installed correctly, but after some time the certificate was removed automatically.

Do you have any idea why the certificate was removed and how can avoid this.

Comment: You need to try your best to reveal more about "after some time the certificate was removed automatically". A few seconds or a few days have significance.